# Installing a program without installation file

Tags: random

I've heard that you can take a program that is already installed in a PC and go home to you r own pc and write a program in any programming language to make it work without having to install the program. I wanted to know how does one go about in achieving that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class of applications you are describing are called Standalone or [Portable Applications.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_application)

In such applications all files that are required to run the application are stored in the same directory as the application file itself. Which is not the way with most applications work, so, you cannot make all applications run in that fashion. There are various guides on Google when you search for 'creating portable applications'.

You might want to look at a good directory of portable applications [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_portable_software)

Comment: I do have an Idea on Portable applications, which are deployed using Xcopy, but in terms of application where some of the keys that are stored in the windows registry how does one the all the registry keys associated to the application and create the application to make it work again?

Comment: You could have some monitor programs running which would detect changes to registry while installation, and replicate the same on the target computer.